# How to write a global get+set method for object

Tags: javascript, jquery, getter-setter

My question is easy to understand, I have an object (or class), and I want to have ONE method which can getting AND setting a property.

In fact, I have no problem to write it for *"simple"* properties. It becomes difficult when my class has object properties, and that I want to access or alter a nested one.

My class:

```
var MyClass = function() {
    this.name = 'defaultName';

    this.list = {
        a: 1,
        b: 6
    };
}
```

Simple class, isn't it? Then, what I write for my method:

```
MyClass.prototype.getset = function(prop) {
    let value = arguments[1];
    let path = prop.split('.');

    prop = this;

    $(path).each(function(i) { prop = prop[this]; }

    if (value) {
        prop = value;
        return this;
    }

    return prop;
}
```

The "get part" works (`MyClass.getset('list.b')` returns 6).
But the "set part"... does not work.

I want that when I execute `MyClass.getset('list.b', 2)`, the `b` property of `list` becomes 2, and that's not the case.

I know why my version is not working (my `prop` variable is just a *"copy"* and does not affect the object itself), but I can't find solution for this...

Thanks for you help!

Comment: _which can getting AND setting a property_ That's where things go south

Comment: The `list` is publicly available from the class, so why bother making a, frankly needlessly complicated, function to re-create already available functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/jtz5asL6/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I know that. I like remaking things, even if it's sometimes useless and that I will not use it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're assigning a primitive, you need to assign to a property of an object for the object to be changed as well. Check if `value`, and if so, navigate to and change from the *next to last* property, rather than the final property. Use `reduce` for brevity:

```js
var MyClass = function() {
  this.name = 'defaultName';

  this.list = {
    a: 1,
    b: 6
  };
}

MyClass.prototype.getset = function(prop, value) {
  const props = prop.split('.');
  const lastProp = props.pop();
  const lastObj = props.reduce((obj, prop) => obj[prop], this);
  if (value) {
    lastObj[lastProp] = value;
    return this;
  } else return lastObj[lastProp];
}

const mc = new MyClass();
mc.getset('list.b', 2);
console.log(mc.list.b);
console.log(mc.getset('list.b'));
```